# gpgsm: Cannot import private key

Tags: gnupg, import, private-key, smime, pkcs

For signing emails, I requested an S/MIME certificate using the German academic DFN service.  AT the end of this process, I get a `.p12` file (PKCS12). I can convert this file to PEM using

```
openssl pkcs12 -in TorstenBronger.p12 -nodes -out /tmp/temp.pem
```

In the PEM file, I can see four certificates (my own and the chain) and the private key.  But importing the `.p12` file into gpgsm fails:

```
$ gpgsm --import TorstenBronger.p12 
gpgsm: data error at "data.objectidentifier", offset 67
gpgsm: error at "bag-sequence", offset 49
gpgsm: error parsing or decrypting the PKCS#12 file
gpgsm: total number processed: 0
```

It does not matter whether or not I removed the password from the key using the roundtripping described in https://serverfault.com/a/633820/47303.

Writing only the certificates to a PEM, I seem to be able to import them into gnupgsm’s database.  But the key is missing.

How can I successfully import the certificates *and* the key into gnupgsm?

Comment: FWIW, roundtripping through Firefox and https://git.scc.kit.edu/-/snippets/572 didn’t help either.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am stuck with the very same problem (also a certificate issued by DFN). Works very well with Thunderbird on KDE neon, but not at all with KMail/Kleopatra/gpgsm.

Comment: I created an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug that is fixed in GnuPG 2.2.35.

See [this mail thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/gnupg-users@gnupg.org/msg40750.html).

Comment: Thanks a million. I downloaded the current AppImage (v. 2.4.0), imported the certificate, and now I can even use it with v. 2.2.7, i.e. the GPG/Kleopatra version currently provided by KDE neon.